# Sort list in either desc or asc, depending on what it currently is

Tags: c#, list, sorting, webforms

I've got a list, and I want to sort the results in the opposite order of what it currently is, to mimic the user clicking the column header hyperlink. Currently, I've the following:

```
 dsList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName));
```

But this only sorts ascending. I know to sort descending I would do:

```
 dsList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName)*-1);
```

but, I don't want to have to detect what it currently is and decide which sort to do.

Make sense?

Gracias.

To clarify, I can't use Reverse because I have more than 1 column that can be sorted by, so I need the ability to specify the value to sort on.

The below works, but not for null values. If there's a blank the sort gets stuck.

```
  dsList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.Surname, y.Surname) * (strB != null && (strA != null && String.Compare(strA, strB) == -1) ? -1 : 1));
```

Comment: The problem is not about will, you HAVE to find a way to detect the current disposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
dsList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName)*(dsList[0] < dsList[1]?-1:1));
```

EDIT: in your comment it seems like you are having issues when there are duplicate or null values... this should fix that

```
dsList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName)*String.CompareOrdinal(dsList[0].DisplayName, dsList[dsList.Length-1].DisplayName));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. dsList is a list of user objects. I can compare dsList[0].DisplayName to dsList[1].DisplayName, but not with the < operator. How to compare string sort order?

Comment: I can get this to work, sort of, but I get stuck if there's a null value for either of the strings to compare.  `  dsList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.Surname, y.Surname) * (strB != null && (strA != null && String.Compare(strA, strB) == -1) ? -1 : 1));`

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully work for nulls and duplicates (which I think is more likely your problem)

Comment: The problem was with nulls, which I've fixed by ensuring there are none! Thanks Jay.

Comment: Actually, your new solution is resulting in an error. dsList is a list of user objects, and has no length property. It's got a count, which I used and got: Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results. IComparer: 'System.Array+FunctorComparer`1'.             `                            dsList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.Surname, y.Surname) * String.CompareOrdinal(dsList[0].Surname, dsList[dsList.Count - 1].Surname));`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Linq extension [Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)? This can allow you to switch between ascending and descending without knowing the current sorting. If you want to use this, make sure you are referencing `System.Core` library and declaring a using directive with `System.Linq` on the top of your source file.

Another way would be creating a class that inherits from List and modifying it a little bit like this:

```
public class LazyReversingList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private Boolean m_SortedAscending;
    private List<T> m_InnerList;

    public Boolean IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean SortedAscending
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SortedAscending;
        }
    }

    public Int32 Count
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureList();
            return m_InnerList.Count;
        }
    }

    public T this[Int32 index]
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureList();
            return m_InnerList[index];
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureList();
            m_InnerList[index] = value;
        }
    }

    private void EnsureList()
    {
        if (m_InnerList == null)
            m_InnerList = new List<T>();
    }

    public Boolean Contains(T item)
    {
        EnsureList();
        return m_InnerList.Contains(item);
    }

    public Boolean Remove(T item)
    {
        EnsureList();
        return m_InnerList.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        EnsureList();
        return m_InnerList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Int32 IndexOf(T item)
    {
        EnsureList();
        return m_InnerList.IndexOf(item);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        EnsureList();
        return m_InnerList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        EnsureList();
        m_InnerList.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        EnsureList();
        m_InnerList.Clear();
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, Int32 arrayIndex)
    {
        EnsureList();
        m_InnerList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public void Insert(Int32 index, T item)
    {
        EnsureList();
        m_InnerList.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(Int32 index)
    {
        EnsureList();
        m_InnerList.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Reverse()
    {
        if (!m_SortedAscending)
        {
            m_InnerList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName));
            m_SortedAscending = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_InnerList.Sort((x, y) => (String.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName) * -1));
            m_SortedAscending = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use Reverse because I have more than 1 column that can be sorted by, so I need the ability to specify the value to sort on.

Comment: Can you explain this better please?

Comment: Well, if the user clicks the Name header, i need the results sorted in the opposite order, by Name (A-->Z, or Z-->A). If the user clicks on the Office column i need it sorted by the Office column.

Comment: What about the second solution?

Comment: Still trying to make it work. So far I've got:                `dsList.Sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayName, y.DisplayName) * (String.Compare(dsList[0].DisplayName, dsList[1].DisplayName)==1 ? -1 : 1));`

Comment: Look at Jay's construct if it could be what you're looking for!

Comment: I've updated my post with a somewhat working solution, thanks to Jay. It doesn't work for null values though, so I'm still stuck.

Comment: To deal with nulls... have a look at those links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want to do is simply reverse the current order each time, you should consider using the [Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) method available in .Net's LINQ

OR

You could simply pass a value for which direction back and forth.  This would allow for binding of sort behavior to the desired state of the page, for this consider a hidden field.